# How to call php variable inside echo statement - Wordpress Plugin Dev

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins, concatenation

I am trying to develop a Wordpress Plugin (to develop my skills) that allows a user to customise their Wordpress login page.

I have a settings page where the user can choose to replace the Wordpress logo. However, I cannot call this option correctly from the database. I have read about string concatenation and nesting php tags but I cannot get this function to work.

```html
<?php

$bglogo = get_option('background_logo');

function custom_login_logo() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
        h1 a { background-image: url(.$bglogo.)  !important; }
          </style>';
}
?>
```

I have tried the below without success:

```html
background-image: url(".$bglogo.")  !important;
```

```html
background-image: url('.$bglogo.')  !important;
```

Is it possible the problem is the style tags?

Comment: What's the generated source?

Comment: its a scope issue `$bglogo` is outside the function scope

Comment: Do PHP Code Snippets normally work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - Made a mistake in previous answer.

Current code:-

```
function custom_login_logo() {
    $bglogo = get_option('background_logo'); ?>
    <style>
        h1 a{
            background-image: url(<?php echo $bglogo; ?>)!important;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: edit is still wrong

Comment: It was indeed a scope issue. Thanks guys.

Comment: does the variable definitely give you back the img src you expect?

Comment: Yes. It works great now the variable has been defined within the function.

Comment: Now it's correct.+1